# Vagrant IP Address Collision Issue

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm having an issue bringing a previously working vagrant box up.

When I run the `up` command with the line `box.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.10"` in it, I get the error:

```
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.

Bridged Network Address: '10.0.0.0'
Host-only Network 'en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)': '10.0.0.0'
```

But when I change that same line to `box.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.10"` it works fine (change number after 3rd period 1 from 0).

In my VirtualBox Host Network Manager, I've got 
`vboxnet1` with the IPv4 Address/Mask `10.0.0.1/24` and `vboxnet2` with `10.0.1.1/24`. Can anyone give me some help as to why I only seem to be able to use the second? I have no other virtual machines running right now.

Answer (score 0):

Has your network configuration changed recently on the host? Maybe a wifi router, LAN adapter, bridge, VPN tunnel, etc is using 10.0.0.x address space. Typing `ifconfig` in a Terminal window will reveal all your network interfaces and their IP allocations.

Comment: Not that I can see. The only boxes at 10.0.x.x are as you'd expect given then virtualbox settings.```vboxnet1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01
 inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
vboxnet2: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 0a:00:27:00:00:02
 inet 10.0.1.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.1.255```